Cannot get rid of "Make "[field name]" transient or serializable." warning from SonarLint on Intellij
SonarLint plugin on Intellij (IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)) shows warnings like: Make "[field name]" transient or serializable. I cannot get rid of it, even though I definitely should.
Here are the details. I have ParentDTO class (SpringBoot annotations here):
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Schema(description = "Description")
public class ParentDTO implements Serializable {
    @NotNull
    @Schema(description = "Test", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED)
    private String test;

    @NotNull
    @Schema(description = "Child", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED)
    private ChildDTO child;
}

and ChildDto class:
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Schema(description = "Child description")
public class ChildDTO {
    @NotNull
    @Schema(description = "Name", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED)
    private String name;
}


With that two classes I spoted Make "child" transient or serializable warning on ParentDto class. Ok, my mistake, ChildDTO class should be also Serializable, so I changed to:
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Schema(description = "Child description")
public class ChildDTO implements Serializable {
    @NotNull
    @Schema(description = "Name", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED)
    private String name;
}


but suprisingly the warning has NOT gone. I tried to:

Restart Intellij (with all caches cleared)
Update SonarList plugin to the newest version
Configure new project on Intellij on a brand new git clone

The warning is still there.
Then I did some stupid thing: I refactored ChildDTO class name to ChildDTOx class name - the warning has gone. What??? When I rolled back the warning appeared again. Next I added new class ChildDTODummy with the same structure as ChildDTO and added reference from ParentDTO:
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Schema(description = "Description")
public class ParentDTO implements Serializable {
    @NotNull
    @Schema(description = "Test", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED)
    private String test;

    @NotNull
    @Schema(description = "Child", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED)
    private ChildDTO child;

    @NotNull
    @Schema(description = "Child dummy", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED)
    private ChildDTODummy childDummy;
}

...and there is no warning like: Make "childDummy" transient or serializable. I also removed implementation of Serializable interface from ChildDummy class and the additional warning still did not appear. What??? I think it should.
Does anybody has an idea what is going on here? Why SonarLint shows warning where it should not, and not showing where it should?
Thanks for any reply.

In order to make it part of the Serialization mechanism you should generate a serial version uid like for example:
private static final long serialVersionUID = 494365558256126188L;

I have found useful adding in IntelliJ ide the following setting:
Settings (ctrl+alt+s shortcut on Windows)
Another tip: usally entities are part of the serialization not dtos

Edited 05/07:
Other solutions can involve invalidating cache or suppress the warning.
About the first on IntelliJ you can search throught settings, it will prompt you how can be trigger the action, i've choosed a keyboard-shortcut as you can see:

After triggering the action you can rebuild your project.
The second one is more a workaround and consist in adding above the "problematic" field the following annotation: @SuppressWarnings("serial")

applying the quickfix will automatically add a generated serial version, hope it helped :)

Thanks, I added serialVersionUID, but unfortunatelly that not resolved the issue. Thanks for nice tip about IntelliJ settings.

Hi, edited the answer but not sure it will fix your problems, surely nice-to-know infos.

hi, "invalidating caches" was one of the first thing i did (I wrote in original request "(..)with all caches cleared(...)" maybe to little precise). Of course I could supress the warning but I was wondering how resolve issue with leaving it (because sometime it may be helpful)
